LauchDarkly flag value specific for test case
I'm trying to unit test a function that is partly controlled by a LaunchDarkly flag. My wish is for the flag to be set to true for every test case but one.
To achieve that I'm trying to set specific attributes in the context for the false test case, that can be then evaluated by the LaunchDarkly evaluator, but I can't seem to find the right setup of context keys, context kind, and attributes to make it work.
Here's what I have:
// Test file
import (
    "github.com/launchdarkly/go-server-sdk/v7/ldcomponents"
    "github.com/launchdarkly/go-server-sdk/v7/testhelpers/ldtestdata"
    ld "github.com/launchdarkly/go-server-sdk/v7"
    ofld "github.com/open-feature/go-sdk-contrib/providers/launchdarkly/pkg"
    "github.com/open-feature/go-sdk/openfeature"
)

func NewTestFlaggingClient() (*ldtestdata.TestDataSource, *ld.LDClient) {
    td := ldtestdata.DataSource()

    var ldConfig ld.Config
    ldConfig.ApplicationInfo.ApplicationID = "testing"
    ldConfig.DataSource = td
    ldConfig.Events = ldcomponents.NoEvents()

    ldClient, err := ld.MakeCustomClient("fake-sdk-key", ldConfig, 5*time.Second)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if err := openfeature.SetProvider(ofld.NewProvider(ldClient)); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return td, ldClient
}

func Test_myMethod(t *testing.T) {
  // ...
  disabledCtx := openfeature.NewEvaluationContext("user",
    map[string]interface{}{
      "disable-flag": true
    })

  td, flagger := flags.NewTestFlaggingClient()
  
  // Here I'm trying to create a flag that will always be true
  // except when I see the context above
  td.Update(td.Flag("method-enabled").
    BooleanFlag().
    VariationForKey("user", "disable-flag", false).
    FallthroughVariation(true),
  )

    t.Run("Skip if flag is not set", func(t *testing.T) {
      // add the disabledCtx to the parent context
      ctx := openfeature.WithTransactionContext(ctx, disabledCtx)

      err := myMethod(ctx)
      // ...
    })
}

// myMethod implementation
func myMethod(ctx context.Context) error {
  // the Flag evaluation always receives this anonymous context, alongside the parent context
  anonCtx := openfeature.NewEvaluationContext("anonymous", map[string]any{
    "kind":      "user",
    "anonymous": true,
  })

  if !p.clients.Flags.Boolean(ctx, "mm-return-processor-enabled", false, anonCtx) {
    return nil
  }
}

I can't really find a working example anywhere, and I tried debugging the openfeature and laumchdarkly packages to see what's breaking, but I've found no way out yet.

Could you at least comment on my answer? I'm not sure why you have a bounty on it, when you are not interested in replies.

@eik My apologies. I am interested in replies, but other stuff came up that required most of my time.

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve here, but with
    td.Update(td.Flag("method-enabled").
        VariationForUser("user1", false).
        FallthroughVariation(true),
    )

you create a flag method-enabled that is false for user1 and true for everybody else. VariationForUser is a shorthand for VariationForKey("user", ..., which is what you are using. I'm unsure if you really meant a user disable-flag, I go with user1 here.
Assuming your method under test:
package main

import (
    "context"

    "github.com/open-feature/go-sdk/openfeature"
)

func MyMethod(ctx context.Context) (bool, error) {
    of := openfeature.GetApiInstance()
    client := of.GetClient()

    val, err := client.BooleanValue(ctx, "method-enabled", false, openfeature.EvaluationContext{})
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }

    return val, nil
}

This test will pass:
package main

import (
    "context"
    "testing"
    "time"

    ld "github.com/launchdarkly/go-server-sdk/v7"
    "github.com/launchdarkly/go-server-sdk/v7/interfaces"
    "github.com/launchdarkly/go-server-sdk/v7/ldcomponents"
    "github.com/launchdarkly/go-server-sdk/v7/testhelpers/ldtestdata"
    ofld "github.com/open-feature/go-sdk-contrib/providers/launchdarkly/pkg"
    "github.com/open-feature/go-sdk/openfeature"
)

func NewTestFlaggingClient() (*ldtestdata.TestDataSource, error) {
    td := ldtestdata.DataSource()

    ldConfig := ld.Config{
        ApplicationInfo: interfaces.ApplicationInfo{
            ApplicationID: "testing",
        },
        DataSource: td,
        Events:     ldcomponents.NoEvents(),
    }

    ldClient, err := ld.MakeCustomClient("fake-sdk-key", ldConfig, 5*time.Second)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if err := openfeature.SetProvider(ofld.NewProvider(ldClient)); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return td, err
}

func TestMyMethod(t *testing.T) {
    td, _ := NewTestFlaggingClient()

    td.Update(td.Flag("method-enabled").
        VariationForUser("user1", false).
        FallthroughVariation(true),
    )

    enabledCtx := openfeature.NewEvaluationContext("user2", nil)

    disabledCtx := openfeature.NewEvaluationContext("user1", nil)

    ctx := context.Background()

    type args struct {
        ctx context.Context
    }
    tests := []struct {
        name    string
        args    args
        want    bool
        wantErr bool
    }{
        {
            name: "enabled",
            args: args{openfeature.WithTransactionContext(ctx, enabledCtx)},
            want: true,
        },
        {
            name: "disabled",
            args: args{openfeature.WithTransactionContext(ctx, disabledCtx)},
            want: false,
        },
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            got, err := MyMethod(tt.args.ctx)
            if (err != nil) != tt.wantErr {
                t.Errorf("MyMethod() error = %v, wantErr %v", err, tt.wantErr)

                return
            }
            if got != tt.want {
                t.Errorf("MyMethod() = %v, want %v", got, tt.want)
            }
        })
    }
}

When you want to use attributes, use:
...
import  "github.com/launchdarkly/go-sdk-common/v3/ldvalue"
...
    td.Update(td.Flag("method-enabled").
        IfMatch("disable-flag", ldvalue.Bool(true)).ThenReturn(false).
        FallthroughVariation(true),
    )

    enabledCtx := openfeature.NewEvaluationContext("user", nil)

    disabledCtx := openfeature.NewEvaluationContext("user", map[string]interface{}{"disable-flag": true})
...

Also, see this document for some attributes mapped from OpenFeature to LaunchDarkly, like anonymous contexts.

As you can easily verify, with MyMethod defined as:
func MyMethod(ctx context.Context) (bool, error) {
    of := openfeature.GetApiInstance()
    client := of.GetClient()

    anonCtx := openfeature.NewEvaluationContext("anonymous", map[string]any{
        "kind":      "user",
        "anonymous": true,
    })

    val, err := client.BooleanValue(ctx, "method-enabled", false, anonCtx)
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }

    return val, nil
}

the tests pass too. With "mm-return-processor-enabled" you won't get what you want, since this flag is not defined anywhere else.

Thank you. This is very helpful, and the links also added some much needed context (heh). It seems to me that one of the biggest differences in your code is that MyMethod is using an empty EvaluationContext when calling .Boolean(), and in my project they're using the anonymous context in my original example. I am not entirely sure if I can actually change that, so assuming I can't for the sake of argument: is it possible to evaluate the flag against some other context property that is not the user? That's my intention.

Of course. It's unclear what you are trying to achieve, though. Perhaps you should formulate your use case, though? Otherwise, When it's helpful, you could at least mark the answer as useful ;)
